# How to create a ROS snap correctly?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorial at https://snapcraft.io/#ros to create a `Ubuntu Snap` from a ROS package on Github. This all goes well until running the `snapcraft` command, from https://snapcraft.io/first-snap/ros/linux/build-and-test, which results in the following error:

```
ERROR: no rosdep rule for 'roscpp_serialization'
Package 'roscpp_serialization' isn't a valid system dependency. Did you forget to add it to catkin-packages? If not, add the Ubuntu package containing it to stage-packages until you can get it into the rosdep database.
```

I'm assuming this means I should change something in the `.yaml` file but I am unsure exactly how this should look. Could anyone offer an example or any guidance?

Here's the `.yaml` file from the tutorial:

```
name: test-ros-talker-listener-test
 version: '0.1'
 summary: ROS Talker/Listener Example
 description: |
  This example launches a ROS talker and listener.
 confinement: devmode
 base: core18
 parts:
  ros-tutorials:
    plugin: catkin
    source: https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials.git
    source-branch: melodic-devel
    source-space: roscpp_tutorials/

 apps:
  test-ros-talker-listener-test:
    command: roslaunch roscpp_tutorials talker_listener.launch
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364156/how-to-create-a-ros-snap-correctly?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2020-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2020-10-26**:
It would be helpful to see the snapcraft.yaml you're using so we can duplicate your results. That tutorial seems to works fine, but it sounds like you're trying to snap something else, correct?

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-10-26**:
Just added this :)

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2020-10-26**:
Wait, that IS the tutorial, no? I just built that and it worked fine. Can you add details regarding which OS/version you're using, as well as how you installed snapcraft and its version?

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-10-27**:
Yes that's right. See answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 and the Snapcraft was version is 2.43.1+18.4. To me this looked strange so I removed it, although Snapcraft version 4.3 remained on the system which did work. Problem solved!

---

Originally posted by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) with karma: 501 on 2020-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2020-10-27**:
You must have had both the snapcraft snap as well as the snapcraft deb installed. The deb is old and not supported anymore, so removing it and using the snap was the right thing to do.